# Date Field shows different times in Frontend and Backend

Tags: datetime

I have a date field applied to a node. When I set the time in the date field to i.e. 10am and render that date to my website like so:

```
echo  date('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime($variables['field_date'][0]['value']));
```

The output is 9:00am. There is only one single timezone set for the whole website, no individual timezones for users are activated.

Comment: This may be because of the timezone . Set the date field setting  "Time zone handling" of the content type as " No time Zone conversion"